In PHP, xml namespaces are being redeclared when the namespace prefix is changed
In my document type declaration, I have the following:
<!ELEMENT all:Test (div)>
<!ATTLIST all:Test
  xmlns:all CDATA #FIXED 'http://www.mrinitialman.com/'
  xmlns     CDATA #FIXED 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'
  xmlns:fnc CDATA #FIXED 'http://www.mrinitialman.com/Functions/'
>
<!ELEMENT div (#PCDATA|fnc:Reference)*>
<!ELEMENT fnc:Reference EMPTY>


The file test.xml looks like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE all:Test SYSTEM "./mrinitialman.dtd">
<all:Test xmlns:all="http://www.mrinitialman.com/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
  xmlns:fnc="http://www.mrinitialman.com/Functions/">
   <div>Testing 123</div>
</all:Test>


My PHP in a test document looks like this:
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
$doc->loadXML(file_get_contents('./test.xml');
echo $doc->saveXML();
?>

My output looks like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE all:Test SYSTEM "./mrinitialman.dtd">
<all:Test xmlns:all="http://www.mrinitialman.com/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
  xmlns:fnc="http://www.mrinitialman.com/Functions/">
   <div xmlns:fnc="http://www.mrinitialman.com/Functions/">Testing 123</div>
</all:Test>

Why is xmlns:fnc="http://www.mrinitialman.com/Functions/" being repeated in the <div> start tag?  Is there a workaround to this, or just an inherent part of PHP working with XML namespaces?

Is that all the relevant code? I cannot reproduce it, neither in my computer nor in 3v4l.org. And my IDE warns that the Functions namespace declaration is never used.

Nevermind;  I found the problem.  I had used a truncated form of my Document Type Definition for the demonstration, and failed to notice that I had altered the Attribute List for the <div> element in the complete document type definition (namely, I included the namespaces in its attribute list)
